# Photos in sql database or filesystem (2012)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, filesystems, storage

There might be several questions about this already but I'd like to get an updated answer since most answer are old now. Which will be better in storage of images, database or filesystem?

---

I think facebook is using database because images can be in various extensions :|
See this links for example: [jpeg](http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/292508_371212639597799_214433131942418_1157212_493691459_n.jpeg) [jpg](http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/292508_371212639597799_214433131942418_1157212_493691459_n.jpg) [png](http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/292508_371212639597799_214433131942418_1157212_493691459_n.png) [gif](http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/292508_371212639597799_214433131942418_1157212_493691459_n.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it may seem so, this is not a matter of taste, but a performance problem.
I have experimented both ways, for projects that are now alive and kicking, and learnt my lesson during their development period.

Storing files in database may seem a nice way to create the all-in-one setup that is easy to deploy, maintain etc. But when it comes to larger files (e.g. hi-res images), it may significantly increase you loading time.

On the other hand, speaking of smaller images, as user avatars, product thumbnails, other thumbnails, it may increase your loading speed, by making fewer requests to the server's file system. In this specific case, it all depends on the SQL skill you may have and the optimization level of your queries.

---

I will give you a suggestion, which I have used myself by now in projects involving many images, and not only those.

Create a table in your database, with roughly the following structure:

```
id            INT(5) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
filename      VARCHAR(255)
fullsize_path CHAR(255)
image         BLOB
mime          CHAR(25)
size          INT(20)
```

Err... you get the idea, the BLOB field is where your image is going. In case it's a thumbnail for something, the fullsize_path will not be left empty and mention the path to the fully sized image.

In this way, when displaying, for example, a page with products, all the queries will be SQL-based, but when a specific product is accessed, the fullsize_path will tell the browser where the big brother can be found.

---

Of course, you have more things to worry about when deploying something like this, and I will outline a few here:

- SQL server performance
- SQL-hosted images' maximum size (in bytes)
- The amount of images to be stored

> Of course, doing some performance tests before is an invaluable practice!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend storing the files in an images/ folder or something like that on your website, and I would save their name with a random number or id and then store that information in a database. That would be a nice combo of both!

Answer (score 0):

I have done systems using both ways of storage before and it usually depends on the context.

For systems accessing large number of files with low server count (usually 1 server), store in files are easier to develop and maintain.

For systems with high server count, and all servers need access to the files. some times i set it up with files and rsync. and some times i store the file in the database and let replication handle it.

The reason Facebook or other sites store their images in databases is most likely because of that. they need the files to be accessed in a lot of servers without needing th overhead of copying the file around.

Answer (score 0):

Storing images in a database is much secure than storing data in file system. But in performance wise it is much efficient to store images in a file system. We have to choose the best way according to our requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the Filetable option as well.  Pluses are simpler programming model (can use T-SQL and Windows API) and simpler management (via SSMS), minuses are that this makes the database larger.  If you pick this option, you will want to place the filetables on a dedicated filegroup(s) and you will want to adjust your backup strategy to include filegroup backups.

Another possibility is to take a look at RBS (remote BLOB store), which shipped as part of the SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack (not in the main product).